# how to check if the form exists and print all the attributes of the form, HTMLUNIT JAVA

Tags: java, forms, htmlunit

//coding in java
//using htmlunit

How to check if a form exists and then if it does how to print all the attributes so that it could be set to some value later.

The page i want to automate has a form that occurs with a  different input id for a particular field everytime its refreshed

getelementbyid("/*differs every time the page is refreshed*/")

and the element can be identified by its id only.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnit supports xpath: [`getFirstByXPath()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getFirstByXPath%28java.lang.String%29) which gives you a lot of flexibility for finding elements in XML or in this case HTML.

You can learn xpath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

As an example, if you wanted the second `<input>` of the first `<form>` on the page you could use `//form[1]/input[2]`